# Using Moq to determine if a method is called

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

It is my understanding that I can test that a method call will occur if I call a higher level method, i.e.:

```
public abstract class SomeClass()
{    
    public void SomeMehod()
    {
        SomeOtherMethod();
    }

    internal abstract void SomeOtherMethod();
}
```

I want to test that if I call `SomeMethod()` then I expect that `SomeOtherMethod()` will be called.

Am I right in thinking this sort of test is available in a mocking framework?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can see if a method in something you have mocked has been called by using Verify, e.g.:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Mock<ITest> mock = new Mock<ITest>();

        ClassBeingTested testedClass = new ClassBeingTested();
        testedClass.WorkMethod(mock.Object);

        mock.Verify(m => m.MethodToCheckIfCalled());
}

class ClassBeingTested
{
    public void WorkMethod(ITest test)
    {
        //test.MethodToCheckIfCalled();
    }
}

public interface ITest
{
    void MethodToCheckIfCalled();
}
```

If the line is left commented it will throw a MockException when you call Verify. If it is uncommented it will pass.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  You must understand something, however.  You CANNNOT mock a method/property that is not abstract or virtual (obviously, all interface methods and properties can be mocked).

Comment: -1: The .Expect(...).Verifiable() is redundant in this code. Using AAA the verify you have is just right. .Verifiable is for usage with .Verify() i,.e. the no arg version. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980554/what-is-the-purpose-of-verifiable-in-moq/1728496#1728496

Comment: @I-- yes it can

Answer (score 6):

No, mock testing assumes you are using certain testable design patterns, one of which is injection. In your case you would be testing `SomeClass.SomeMethod`  and `SomeOtherMethod` must be implemented in another entity which needs to be interfaced.

Your `Someclass` constructor would look like `New(ISomeOtherClass)`. Then you would mock the `ISomeOtherClass` and set expectation on its `SomeOtherMethod` to be called and verify the expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I agree that the [@Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/347907/3311799) is the recommended way to go I just want to add one alternative way which is provided by `moq` off the self.

Since `SomeClass` is `abstract` it is indeed mockable, but `public void SomeMehod()` isn't. The point is to find the way to mock and somehow invoke that method and then using `CallBase` propagate the call to the `SomeOtherMethod()`. It might sound as a hack but it is simple in essence. It could be used in the case if the proposed refactoring is not possible.

```
// This class is used only for test and purpose is make SomeMethod mockable
public abstract class DummyClass : SomeClass
{
    public virtual void DummyMethod() => base.SomeMethod();
}
```

Then you could setup `DummyMethod()` to propagate the call by setting `CallBase` flag.

```
//Arrange
var mock = new Mock<DummyClass>();
mock.Setup(m => m.DummyMethod()).CallBase();

//Act
mock.Object.SomeMethod();

//Assert
mock.Verify(m => m.SomeOtherMethod(), Times.Once);
```

Comment: Downvoted because it's more complicated and requires a boilerplate DummyClass

Comment: upvoted because sometimes you cannot refactor and you need to test the implementation as it stands