# Test if method in ClassA has been called from another method in ClassA

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

It is possible to test if a method has been called using [Moq and dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347818/using-moq-to-determine-if-a-method-is-called). However, is it possible to test if one method in a class calls another within the same class?

For example, I want to test that if I log a certain exception, that an information message is logged as well.

The method is:

```
public void Error(string message, Exception exception, long logId = 0)
{
    var int32 = (int)logId;
    Info("Id was converted to an int so that it would fit in the log: " + logId, int32);
    Error(message, exception, int32);
}
```

This was my attempt at unit testing it. The test fails, is there any way that it can it be done?

```
void logging_an_error_with_a_long_id_also_logs_info()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ILogger>();
    var testedClass = new Logger();
    var counter = 0;

    testedClass.Error("test" + counter++, new Exception("test" + counter), Int64.MaxValue);

    mock.Verify(m => m.Info(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()));
}
```

Since the `Info` and `Error` methods are in the same class (ClassA), I don't believe I can pass ClassA as a dependency into ClassA. So does it not need tested?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417048/how-to-verify-another-method-in-the-class-was-called-using-moq).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best you're going to be able to do is to make `Info` `virtual`. This will allow you to create a `Mock<Logger>`, set `CallBase = true`, and verify that `Info` was called.

```
var mock = new Mock<Logger> 
{
    CallBase = true
};

mock.Object.Error("test" + counter++, new Exception("test" + counter), Int64.MaxValue);

mock.Verify(m => m.Info(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()));
```

This way, you're still calling the actual implementation of `Error`, but you've used Moq to verify the `Info` method was called.

Comment: +1 this works when Mock<Logger> is used because the real class is needed. Doesn't work for interface Mock<ILogger>.

Answer (score 5):

It feels like you're trying to test the wrong thing.  It's not really important that the `Info` method on your class is called from the `Error` method, what's important is that the behaviour of the `Info` method occurs.  How it happens is an implementation detail of the class.

If I had a math class with two functions:

```
public int Mult(int x, int y) {
    return x*y;
}

public int Sqr(int x) {
    return Mult(x,y);
}
```

I wouldn't test that calling `Sqr` called out to the `Mult` function, I would test `Sqr(4)==16`.  It doesn't matter if that calculation takes place in the Sqr method, or in another method of the class.

Whilst @Andrew's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31140836/592182) is probably what you're after, mocking the class you're testing tends to lead to tightly coupled, brittle tests.

If it's impractical to test the call by observing it's side effects, then it may be a sign that the implementation could use a bit of refactoring.

Comment: It's easier to say there's probably a better way than to provide a better way

Comment: @Hoppe Whilst that's true, in order to provide a better way one often needs more context than is provided (for example I have no idea what the contents of your Error or Info methods is).  Sometimes the best that can be done is to indicate an alternate direction, which in some will open a door that will allow them to look at their problem in a different way..