# What is the purpose of VerifyAll() in Moq?

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I read the question at [What is the purpose of Verifiable() in Moq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980554/what-is-the-purpose-of-verifiable-in-moq) and have this question in my mind:

What is the purpose of `VerifyAll()` in Moq?

Comment: Remember that you should not be stacking up Asserts in your Arrange. You should be Asserting. Thus dont use either Verify or VerifyAll - it's the wrong way to think about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980554/what-is-the-purpose-of-verifiable-in-moq/1728496#1728496

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`VerifyAll()` is for verifying that all the expectations have been met. Suppose you have:

```
myMock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething()).Returns(1);
mySut.Do();
myMock.VerifyAll(); // Fail if DoSomething was not called
```

Comment: This doesnt illustrate the diff between V and VA very well though (which is what the OP asked for), does it?

Comment: You use Verify when you can use the AAA syntax and when you don't need to setup expectation on the mock object.

Answer (score 59):

I will try to complete [@ema's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3716623/17242583), probably it will give more insights to the readers. Imagine you have **mocked** object, which is a dependency to your **sut**. Let's say it has two methods and you want to set them up in order to not get any exceptions or create various scenarios to your **sut**:

```
var fooMock = new Mock<Foo>();
fooMock.Setup(f => f.Eat()).Returns("string");
fooMock.Setup(f => f.Bark()).Returns(10);

_sut = new Bar(fooMock.Object);
```

So that was **arrange** step. Now you want to run some method which you want to actually test(now you **act**):

```
_sut.Test();
```

Now you will **assert** with `VerifyAll()`:

```
fooMock.VerifyAll();
```

What you will test here? You will test whether your **setup** methods were **called**. In this case, if either `Foo.Eat()` or `Foo.Bark()` were not called you will get an exception and test will fail. So, actually, you **mix** arrange and assert steps. Also, you cannot check how many times it was called, which you can do with `.Verify()` (imagine you have some parameter `Param` with property called `Name` in your `Eat()` function):

```
fooMock.Verify(f => f.Eat(It.Is<Param>(p => p.Name == "name")), Times.Once);
```

Comment: This totally breaks Command Query Separation, though

Comment: What is this "sut" you mention?

Comment: @O'Rooney it's an object you are writing unit tests for. It can be translated as "System Under Test", quite a common naming convention, sorry for not being clear :)

Comment: OK, thanks. So it's an acronym - should be in captials. But perhaps just write "object being tested" for easier reading.