# Test if id is greater than 0 in Xunit

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, xunit

Can anyone help me to write the second assert for the following unit test? Actually I want to test if CategoryId is greater than 0 and I want to use my response data (CategoryId is auto generated here because of Identity column)

```
 [Fact]
 public async Task PostValidObjectReturnsOkResult()
 {
     //Arrange
     Mock <ICategoryService> m = new Mock <ICategoryService>();
           
     CategoryDTO myData = new CategoryDTO()
     {
          CategoryName = "Items" 
     };

     m.Setup(repo => repo.CreateCategory(myData));

     CategoryController c = new CategoryController(m.Object);

     //Act
     ActionResult response = await c.Post(myData);//response data
        
     //Assert
     Assert.IsType <OkObjectResult>(response);
}
```

I tried the followings but it did not work:

```
Assert.NotEqual(0,(response.Value as CategoryDTO).CategoryId);
Assert.True(((response.Value as CategoryDTO).CategoryId) > 0);
```

Comment: Please include any error details that may be occurring.

Comment: The error says : "ActionResult" does not contain a definition for Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it like this:

```
var okResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(response);
Assert.NotEqual(0, (okResult.Value as CategoryDTO).CategoryId);
```

Also I changed this line of code:

```
m.Setup(repo => repo.CreateCategory(myData));
```

to the following code because we need to specify Returns() in order to give you some random number for CategoryId

```
m.Setup(i => i.CreateCategory(It.IsAny<CategoryDTO>())).Returns(() => Task.FromResult(myData));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Assert.IsType` will return the casted type.  Try:

```
var okResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(response);

Assert.True(okResult.Value.CategoryId > 0);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I am getting error for CategoryId here it says "object does not have definition for CategoryId"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are trying to test is the behavior of assigning values from `ICategoryService` back to the `CategoryDTO` object. In this case the mock implementation of `ICategoryService` will need to provide the same results as the concrete implementation. It looks like you are using Moq, and in order to implement a check you might [use a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834718/4027768) to check the following:

```cs
var expectedCategoryId = 42;
m.Setup(repo => repo.CreateCategory(myData))
 .Callback(() => myData.CategoryId = expectedCategoryId);

// The rest of the testing code

Assert.Equal(expectedCategoryId, resultValue.CategoryId);
```

If the object that is passed into the service is the same object that is returned in the controller's OK response, then you may want to adjust the test to [verify the expectations of the mock service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716561/what-is-the-purpose-of-verifyall-in-moq):

```cs
// The rest of the testing code

m.VerifyAll();
```

Also as @Jonesopolis suggests instead of casting types using the `as` operator, you should use the return result from `Assert.IsType<T>`. With a slight adjustment to their code, this should simplify what your test logic should look like:

```cs
// The rest of the testing code

var okObjectResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(response);
var resultValue = Assert.IsType<CategoryDTO>(okObjectResult);
Assert.True(resultValue.CategoryId > 0, "Result value does not have CategoryId assigned");
```

Also note that I have included a message alongside the `Assert.True` check. This allows the testing framework to give better feedback when the test fails.

Comment: thank you for the answer I am trying your solution in my code.