# How to MOQ a repository and ensure that the method is called using VerifyAll()?

Tags: c#-4.0, moq, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

This is the repository class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Dealer.Rails.Common.Utils;
using Dealer.Rails.Repository.Entities.C3;
using Dealer.Rails.Repository.Repositories.C3.Interfaces;
using Dealer.Rails.Repository.Repositories.Soar;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Dealer.Rails.Repository.Repositories.C3
{
    public class VehicleStagingRepository : BaseRepository, IVehicleStagingRepository
    {

        public VehicleStagingRepository(ILogger<VehicleStagingRepository> logger)
          : base(logger)
        {

        }

        public void SaveVehicleStaging(List<ImportStageVh> vehicleStagingRecords, C3Context c3Context)
        {
            using (var transaction = c3Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var vehicleStagingRecordBeforeSaving = new ImportStageVh();

                try
                {
                    foreach (var vehicleStagingRecord in vehicleStagingRecords)
                    {
                        vehicleStagingRecordBeforeSaving = vehicleStagingRecord;
                        c3Context.ImportStageVh.Add(vehicleStagingRecord);
                        c3Context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                catch (TimeoutException tex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    _logger.LogError(LoggingEvents.SaveEmployeeStaging, tex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    _logger.LogError(LoggingEvents.SaveEmployeeStaging, ex, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vehicleStagingRecordBeforeSaving));
                    throw new Exception(vehicleStagingRecordBeforeSaving.ToString(),ex);
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }


  }
}
```

This is the Xunit Test Cases using MOQ.

```
using Dealer.Rails.Repository.Entities.C3;
using Dealer.Rails.Repository.Repositories.C3;
using Dealer.Rails.Repository.Repositories.C3.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Moq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xunit;

namespace Dealer.Rails.Repository.Tests.Repositories.Rails
{

    public class VehicleStagingRepositoryTests
    {

        [Fact]
        [Trait("Repositories", "C3")]
        public void Should_Dump_Records_To_Vehicle_Staging_Dump()
        {
            // Arrange
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<C3Context>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=dev.c3.dealertrack.corp;Initial Catalog=c3_bmc;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");

            var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<VehicleStagingRepository>>();

            var mockC3Context = new C3Context(optionsBuilder.Options);
           // var vehicleStagingRecords = new List<ImportStageVh>();

            var mockRepository = new Mock<IVehicleStagingRepository>();
            mockRepository.Setup(x => x.SaveVehicleStaging(It.IsAny<List<ImportStageVh>>(), mockC3Context));

            // System under test is TemplateColumnRepository
            var sut = new VehicleStagingRepository(mockLogger.Object);

            // Act
            sut.SaveVehicleStaging(new List<ImportStageVh>(), mockC3Context);

            // Assert
            mockRepository.Verify();
            // mockRepository.Verify(m=>m.SaveVehicleStaging(vehicleStagingRecords,mockC3Context),Times.Once,"Failed to call SaveVehicleStaging method");
        }


    }
}
```

MOQ should allow me to independently test the repository. The issues that I am facing are

1. In the line optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer.. If use optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Some dummy connection string"); The code throws an exception. It my opinion it should not.
2. In the line  mockRepository.Verify();, If use mockRepository.VerifyAll(), it fails at line

[image: Failing during tests]
3. Even the next commented line is throwing error. In my opinions it should have executed SaveStagingVehicle method atleast once.

Please guide me in resolving these issues.

Comment: Setups need to be `.Verifiable()` in order for `.Verify()` to work. VerifyAll also assumes that all the mockable members have been setup. Also method under test it tightly coupled to implementation concerns to me a easy to test in isolation. If you are getting database errors then this is an integration test and not a unit test.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980554/what-is-the-purpose-of-verifiable-in-moq/1728496#1728496