# Mocking and testing the LogError message using Moq and xUnit

Tags: c#, mocking, ilogger

I have a class level ILogger which is set up with the ILoggerFactory in the constructor.  The logger is then used within a method within that class and this works perfectly.

I am struggling on how to Mock the ILogger and ILoggerFactory so I can unit test the LogError message.  Can anyone show me an example of this?

I am using xUnit and Microsoft.Extentions.Logging for the loggin

```
//This is my unit test project
[Fact]
public void TestLogErrorMessage()
{
MyClass myClass = new MyClass  (MockLoggerFactory().Object);

    var result = myClass.Mymethod("a")

    //How do I test the LogError message???
}


//Not sure if this is correct
private Mock<ILoggerFactory> MockLoggerFactory()
{
           Mock<ILoggerFactory> mockLoggerFactory = new 
Mock<ILoggerFactory>(MockBehavior.Default);
    mockLoggerFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateLogger(It.IsAny<string>()))
                           .Returns(MockLogger().Object);

        return mockLoggerFactory;
}

private Mock<ILogger> MockLogger()
{        
       var logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
       return logger;
}
```

---

```
//This is the class/method i need to test
private readonly ILogger logger;

public MyClass(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
       if (loggerFactory != null)
       {
           this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyClass>();
       }
}


public string Mymethod(string msg)
{
       if(msg = "a")
       {
           this.logger.LogError($"error");
       }

       return "a string";
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

This is what finally worked for me, successful verification of `LogError` call:

```
var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger>();
Expression<Action<ILogger>> logAction = x =>
    // You can change this up with other severity levels:
    x.Log<It.IsAnyType>(LogLevel.Error,
        It.IsAny<EventId>(),
        It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
        It.IsAny<Exception>(),
        It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>());
    loggerMock.Setup(logAction).Verifiable();
    // Call a method that calls LogError here.
    loggerMock.Object.LogError("test");
    loggerMock.Verify(logAction, Times.Once);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

(*note: this does not work in this specific case because `LogError` is an extension method, see below for an update*):

```
Mock<ILogger> _logger; // declare it somewhere where your test can access it

[Fact]
public void TestLogErrorMessage()
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(MockLoggerFactory().Object);

    var result = myClass.Mymethod("a")

    _logger.Verify();
}


private Mock<ILoggerFactory> MockLoggerFactory()
{
    _logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
    _logger.Setup(log => log.LogError(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();
    Mock<ILoggerFactory> mockLoggerFactory = new Mock<ILoggerFactory>(MockBehavior.Default);
    mockLoggerFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateLogger(It.IsAny<string>()))
                           .Returns(_logger.Object);

    return mockLoggerFactory;
}
```

The key thing to note is the call to `Verifiable()` after setting up the `ILogger` mock. You can read a bit more about `Verifiable()` in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/980554/1344058). After your test ran, you can check whether the method was called by calling `.Verify()` on the mock.

Depending on your needs, you could set this up in the constructor of your test class (if you need it for all/most tests) or directly inside your test method. You could also return it alongside the `ILoggerFactory`. The point is to hold onto the logger so you can verify against it that the method was called.

For your specific case (trying to verify calls to `ILogger.LogError`) you must not mock `LogError`, but the underlying method [`ILogger.Log`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger.log?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILogger_Log__1_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LogLevel_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_EventId___0_System_Exception_System_Func___0_System_Exception_System_String__). That could look like this:

```
var formatter = new Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>((a, b) => "");
m.Setup(x => x.Log<It.IsAnyType>(LogLevel.Error, 
                                 It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                                 It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
                                 It.IsAny<Exception>(), 
                                 formatter))
  .Verifiable();
```

Another alternative would be to make a fake implementation of `ILogger` and return that from the `Mock<ILoggerFactory>`:

```
mockLoggerFactory.Setup(_ => _.CreateLogger(It.IsAny<string>())
                 .Returns(new FakeLogger());

public class FakeLogger : ILogger
{
    public static bool LogErrorCalled { get; set; }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => true;

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if(logLevel == LogLevel.Error)
        {
            LogErrorCalled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And then after your test you can check whether `FakeLogger.LogErrorCalled` is `true`. This is simplified for your specific test - you can get more elaborate than this of course.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise.  However I tried this and now I'm getting the following error within the MockLoggerFactory method:   System.NotSupportedException: 'Invalid setup on an extension method: log => log.LogError(It.IsAny<String>(), new[] {  })'  It crashes on this line:   _logger.Setup(log => log.LogError(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();

Comment: Ah right, the `ILogger` stuff is almost exlusively done with extension methods. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I went with your FakeLogger solution because I cant use IsAnyType on our version of Moq (4.8.1).  And there are no plans to upgrade to 13.1 at the moment. The FakeLogger solution works a treat!!  Thank you so much you're a star!

Comment: If this answered your question, consider upvoting / accepting it to mark your question solved.