# Best way to write a unit test which asserts that an object has been set with a newly instantiated value?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, object, pass-by-reference

say I have a class:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and in a method I instantiate it:

```
public void SomeMethod(Person person)
{
   person = new Person()
}
```

Before the person was passed in it had values set.

What is the best way to assert that `SomeMethod` set the passed reference to a newly instantiated object?

All I can think of is to check all the nullable properties are empty and the non-nullable values have default values.

Is there a better way than this?

Comment: `write a unit test to ensure a class has been newly instantiated?` say what?

Comment: You don't trust that new calls the class constructor? Bizarre.

Comment: It's not that I don't trust it. I'm trying to test that it has been called. Essentially that the person has been reset.

Comment: Posting code that compiles may make question more clear... Possible checking "reference equal" between passed in person and resulting person is what you are looking for...

Comment: checking the reference equal would only test it was a different object. Not that it was a newly instantiated object.

Comment: I guess if you really want to check all the values to make sure they're set to a newly instantiated value, you could write a function which checks every field of Person and returns true or false

Comment: What unit test framework are you using? I know with Moq, you can test that a method has been called: http://stackoverflow.com/a/347907/279516. That would make this question a duplicate.

Comment: What is the context of the question? I can't believe you would be writing a unit test to verify the operation of the compiler, as that would be a magnificent waste of time.

Comment: Just to be clear, SomeMethod will not set the caller's reference to a newly instantiated object. All it does is set its own, local variable to a newly instantiated object. Maybe this is causing some confusion?

Comment: Even if the object is passed by reference, indeed it's a copy of the reference that is passed to a method, so it will not be set when outside of the method. If you want set a new value (instance of `Person`) to the reference passed to `SomeMethod` you need to use the `ref`  keyword: `public void SomeMethod(ref Person person)`