# C# using Moq to delete items from a Mock Repository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I am trying to do a test delete using the Moq framework in C# and I am testing that the items were removed.

At the bottom, if I set int count to be events.Count, it returns 3. Brilliant!!
However if i set it to be EventsMockDatabase.Count(), it returns 5 despite the fact that the mock has been setup to return events.Count.

Can anyone help me explain why?

```
    [Test]
    public void DeleteDuplicateEventDetailsFromRows()
    {
        var event1 = new EventLogObj() { RecordId = 1, TableKey = "PERSON_CODE=1", Status = "S" };
        var event2 = new EventLogObj() { RecordId = 2, TableKey = "PERSON_CODE=2", Status = "S" };
        var event3 = new EventLogObj() { RecordId = 3, TableKey = "PERSON_CODE=3", Status = "S" };
        var event4 = new EventLogObj() { RecordId = 4, TableKey = "PERSON_CODE=2", Status = "S" };
        var event5 = new EventLogObj() { RecordId = 5, TableKey = "PERSON_CODE=1", Status = "S" };

        var events = new List<EventLogObj>() { event1, event2, event3, event4, event5 };

        var mockEventsRepository = new Mock<IEventRepository>();

        mockEventsRepository.Setup(ev => ev.GetEvents())
            .Returns(events);

        mockEventsRepository.Setup(ev => ev.DeleteEvent(It.IsAny<decimal>()))
            .Callback((decimal RecID) =>
            {
                events.RemoveAll(e => e.RecordId == RecID);
            });

        mockEventsRepository.Setup(ev => ev.Count())              
            .Returns(events.Count);

        IEventRepository EventsMockDatabase = mockEventsRepository.Object;

        var eventLogObjects = new List<EventLogObj>();
        var duplicateEventLogObjects = new List<EventLogObj>();

        foreach (EventLogObj elo in EventsMockDatabase.GetEvents())
        {
            var existing = eventLogObjects.Where(
                e => e.TableKey.Equals(elo.TableKey)
            ).ToList();

            if (existing.Count == 0)
            {
                eventLogObjects.Add(elo);
            }
            else
            {
                duplicateEventLogObjects.Add(elo);
            }
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(2, duplicateEventLogObjects.Count);

        foreach (EventLogObj e in duplicateEventLogObjects)
        {
            // delete by id
            EventsMockDatabase.DeleteEvent(e.RecordId);
        }

        int count = events.Count; // EventsMockDatabase.Count(); // WHY!!!?

        Assert.AreEqual(3, count);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value that is returned is stored when you `Setup` the Mock, so in this instance, the size of the initial list (5).

You can get round it by instead setting up the mock with a delegate:

```
mockEventsRepository.Setup(ev => ev.Count())
    .Returns(() => { return events.Count; });
```

As an aside, you do know that your current test wouldn't test any production code, it's simply testing if you've set your mock up to simulate a repository?

Comment: Brilliant! That works. Thanks - and yes I know it wont work on production. This is just to define the steps I intend to take for my live dataset.

Comment: I think the point @forsvarir makes here bears repeating: you should rewrite this test as it is currently only testing itself and not actual code. Generally when you use fakes/stubs/mocks/watever you want to call it using a mocking framework, you don't provide an implementation (like the list of events in your example). Rather, I usually verify whether the correct messages were sent to mocked collaborators. So instead of managing a list of events in your tests, just check that the delete event method was called correctly. If this requires GetEvents to return something, just return dummy data.

Comment: Ok I was using TDD to verify the steps I take when working on live data will work and really want to understand mocks. So @prgmtc you are suggesting i can just check the delete method is called correctly. The way I would do this is return a count of the data source is less after than before. All I have to do is translate that into code now!!! Any tips/samples?

Comment: @Ozzy I believe the point is you don't need to simulate the real behaviour with your mocks.  What's important is that your code under test calls out to say `DeleteEvent` on your mock, passing in any relevant parameters.  Have a look at things like http://stackoverflow.com/a/347907/592182